# Fastest way to search for an attribute in org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, regex

I have an input document from which I would like to search for an attribute in the fastest manner possible. Eg: below's a pretty silly example:

```
<PossibleSuspects>
  <PossibleSuspect name="A" id="423" character="shady"/>
  <PossibleSuspect name="B" id="423" character="normal"/>
  <PossibleSuspect name="C" id="423" character="normal"/>
  <PossibleSuspect name="A" id="423" character="shady"/>
</PossibleSuspects>
```

Basically, I want to get the `name` attribute of rows where `character` is shady. I am okay with the first such match (other's can be ignored/will have same `name`).

I considered looping over the whole document and getting the first match vs doing a regex search after converting document to string.

Which would be faster?

Comment: I don't recommend to use regex, but if speed matters, you can choose a pull parser (without validation) that doesn't need to build the dom tree. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If speed really matters, you should go for the second approach, searching the string document with regex (lucky you, [XML is no HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). But you should take into consideration that ordering of attributes in XML is not guaranteed. Also a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) may help.

If simplicity of your code is more important, I suggest to use Xpath

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String name = xpath.evaluate("//PossibleSuspect[@character='shady']/@name",document);
```

And its not that slow either.

Comment: While XML is certainly more easily parsed, [it's not as simple as it appears at first glance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/702222/1831987).

Comment: agreed, it's a tradeoff between performance and flexibility/compatibility. I'd prefer the xpath way as I've rarely seen occasions where xml processing is really time-critical. Nevertheless, an event driven approach such as SAX oder XMLStreams is probably a good choice as well.